# Why wordpress .htaccess automatically update by new code?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a serious problem. I am looking for some assistance.

I have a wordpress site. There is some code in the .htaccess file installed automatically or after installing a plugin. I am not actually sure why this has happened. Do you have any idea?

```
#FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/1h-fast-php54 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

For this code I got a warning from wordpress backend.

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

When I remove those code from .htaccess it works again.

The last plugin I used was **SIP Reviews Shortcode for WooCommerce** and **YITH WooCommerce Advanced Reviews**.

Can anyone give me any idea why those portion of code added in the .htaccess

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is a plugin that has done this... one that might be corrupt or just not work very well.  At first I thought it was a security thing, which it could be... meaning something that you've actually asked (likely unknowingly) a plugin to do for you.

I suggest you disable/deactivate plugins you've installed recently (right before you started having this error), and then only enable the ones you REALLY want/need **ONE AT A TIME**.

*By re-enabling them one at a time, you should be able to determine which one is corrupting your site.  You'll likely be able to find a suitable replacement for it in the WordPress.org Plugin Repository very quickly.*

Remember that a lot of plugins (especially free ones) are put up for other users to download as soon as the authors can get them up, and not necessarily only until they are absolutely pristine.

Good luck.

---

Upon looking at your original post again, it looks like some program is trying to append rules to your php system as a third-party program?  This could be server-related (contact your hosting company), or it could also somehow be another WordPress Plugin issue.  One of those should be the root of the problem.